# Why are my html element values objects not arrays, and why are they not equivalent to each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to check if the  value matches the initial value, but the `if` ends up returning false and my save dialogue doesn't appear.

They end up both being objects which i do not want, i want to compare both as ARRAYS.

```
  var inital = document.getElementById("roleDropdown").getAttribute("data-inital")
  var inital = inital.split(",");
  $("#roleDropdown").change((e) => {

    var currentVal = $(e.currentTarget).val();

    console.log(inital)
    console.log(currentVal)
    console.log(typeof inital)
    console.log(typeof currentVal)
    console.log(inital == currentVal)

    if(inital === currentVal) {
        saveDialog.classList.remove("shown");
    } else {
        saveDialog.classList.add("shown");
    }
  });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4olF.png)

Comment: Arrays ARE objects in JS. That’s why the `typeof` operator returns `"object"`. Equality checks on objects will only return true if both operands are the same object, not if they are two different objects that just happen to contain the same values. To compare two different objects you need to create your own function for that, or use one of the countless available libraries that have such functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, something like this should work:

```js
  var dropdown = $('#roleDropdown');
  var initial = dropdown.data('initial');
  var initialValues = initial.split(',');
  dropdown.change(function(){

    var matches = true;
    var currentValues = $(this).val().split(',');
    // first, make sure the arrays are the same length, if not, they cant match
    if (initialValues.length !== currentValues.length) {
      matches = false;
    } else {
      // check if all the values in the inital array are still in the new array
      $.each(initialValues, function(i, value) {
        if ($.inArray(value, currentValues) === -1) {
          // mark this as not matching and stop checking here
          matches = false;
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
    var text = matches ? 'matches' : 'doesnt match';
    $('#saveDialog').text(text); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="roleDropdown" data-initial="three,two,one">
  <option>select one</option>
  <option value="one,two,three">one,two,three</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
</select>

<div id="saveDialog">
  
</div>
```